# On release event on a slider?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm making a slider control to a throttle control, and I want it to go to its startposition when I release it with my finger.

I've tried LostFocus but that event needs you to click something else... And it might be problematic as I have two sliders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ManipulationEnded event should do the trick

[MSDN UIElement.ManipulationEnded Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try PreviewMouseUp / PreviewStylusUp event ?